# How to run build on remote server using Git?

Tags: git, github, deployment

I want automatically/manually, when new code is getting to the dev branch on my remote GitHub repository, to be pulled from my remote server, built and run.

I know GitHub Webhooks, but they only allow URLS that will be curled. For that task I can make a node server in my remote host listen for those HTTP requests. But I wonder if there is a better approach, using Git instead.

I have thought about setting another remote which will be called "staging" or "production", beside the "origin" which is GitHub, and every time the Github origin receives a new pull to the dev branch, it will push it forward to the "staging"/"production" remotes.

I have looked for lots of articles out there but found nothing that actually describes the whole process, from scratch.

Comment: Git isn't a deployment tool. Search for "deployment" along with whatever language you're using to find a bunch of possible tools. Pick one or two and try them out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Continuous deployments (**CI**) tools like (**gitlab CI,Drone,etc..**) if you need just pulling your modifications on Production server Try use **Capistrano**.
The simplest solution for me is using [FABRIC](http://www.fabfile.org/) and you can build you code.
Example :

- Install fabric
- Create a fabfile.py
- Put this code inside and replace all variables (user_ssh,/path_to_project,ip_server)

  ```
  from fabric.api import env , run , put

  prod_env = {
    'name' : 'prod' ,
    'user' : 'user_ssh',
    'deploy_to' : '/path_to_project',
    'hosts' : ['ip_server'],
  }

  def set_config(env_config):
    for key in env_config:
       env[key] = env_config[key]

  def prod():
    set_config(prod_env)


  def deploy():
    run("cd %s && git pull -r",env.deploy_to)
    run("You command to build and run")
  ```

Now run:

> fab prod deploy

Hope it helps